# cookie and security in react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, mobx

I made an admin panel in reactJs that manages thousands of people. I want to keep the admin logged in for 30 minutes. After logging in using username and password the server sends the userId and I store that Id in the cookie because for every request I should send the userId in the header. and also made a cookie cookie that shows that the session hasn't ended yet. and on compenentDidMount I put a condition that if the login cookie is exist make a variable true, something like this:

```js
if (this.store.cookieExist("4DeHn6")) {
  this.store.changeSession(true);
  this.store.changeId(this.uId);
  else {
    this.store.changeSession(null);
    this.store.changeId(null);
  }
```

and using react-router if the session is open I render the page else redirect it to login page with a code like this

```js
<Route
                      exact
                      path="/locations"
                      render={() =>
                        !this.store.openSession ? (
                          <Redirect to="/loginPage" />
                        ) : (
                          <Locations />
                        )
                      }
                    />
```

I'm using mobx for state management.

the only thing that I did is making the two cookie names a string generated with password generator. I'm really worried for the security of my application because I think if anyone inspect my code in browser can find those two cookie and log in and get the sensitive data.
for the first part of the project there is no token used in the server.
is there any better and more secure way of doing this.
  appreciate any help.

Comment: front-end code is never secure. You should decide whether to show the page on the server side, based on a session instead of a user accessible cookie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end, the server is responsible to respond only to requests that have a valid token.

After a login process where you have stablished a token that is being sent in every request headers, the server is able to tell if the token is still valid and give you the expected response or tell you that you are not allowed to make that request by sending a `401 Unauthorised` response.

If you are using some middleware like axios to handle your http requests, you could easily [set up an interceptor](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors) that handles `401` responses and send you to the login page. Something like this:

```
responseError: error => {
    switch (errorCode) {
      case 401:
          // your logout logic: delete the cookie, and set the session to false
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
}
```

This will trigger a render where your session would be false, redirecting the user to the login page with your current logic. And also will improve the security of your app by don't responding to invalid or expired tokens.

I hope that helps!

Comment: thank you but the problem is that in the first phase of the project that is about 2 month the server doesn't have any token so I should make my code as secure as possible so I don't get into any trouble until the second phase.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use "cryptr" package to encrypt 
I did something like this:

and then did a encryption and encrypt my secret code and used it as secret code in my code
something like this:

```
const cryptr = new Cryptr("EQqwmBsYQfptNPmHEkjVXSVvJFsE5XbsLFkzMj2WVcDcQHELFTB6JLF35tQfzrf6");
```